# Fig tree moth treatment?

Tags: figs

Hello I've learned from a previous question in 2019 that the holes in my fig leaves with veins left and a cottony substance on a few are from a Tortrix moth. There was no solution in the thread on how this should be dealt with though. Can anyone can tell me? I am in northern France, the tree fruits well (except last year when we had a really wet spring) and so far they are only on the lower leaves. Suggestions gladly received!

Comment: Can you add a picture?